# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\homepageController::edit_web_services(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected

Tags: laravel

my function

```
public function post_sofware_technology(Request $request)
{
    $titile = $request->input('category_title');
    $excerpt = $request->input('Excerpt');
    $post = new posts();
    $post->post_title = $titile;
    $post->post_excerpt = $excerpt;

    $post->save();
    $soft_id = $post->id;
    $this->edit_web_services($soft_id);
}
```

Another Function

```
public function edit_web_services($soft_id)
{
    $soft = $soft_id;
    dd($soft);
}
```

I want to pass my  `$soft_id = $post->id;` value from `post_sofware_technology()` method to `edit_web_services($soft_id)` within the same controller.

Comment: You are passing an argument in your example. Is there somewhere else where you're calling `edit_web_services()`?

Comment: I want to use this value $soft_id  other functions also within the same controller.

Comment: Ok. Is it not possible to pass `$soft_id` to those functions as well when you call them?

Comment: how can I use my one function variable to use another function

Comment: I have to display the content  with this id from another function

Comment: Can you at least show the "other" functions you want to use and how you want to use them?

Comment: I want to display which i posted here in another function ..?

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
public function post_sofware_technology(Request $request)
{
    $titile = $request->input('category_title');
    $excerpt = $request->input('Excerpt');
    $post = new posts();
    $post->post_title = $titile;
    $post->post_excerpt = $excerpt;

    $post->save();
    $soft_id = $post->id;
    return $this->edit_web_services($soft_id);
}
```

Comment: i want to display what i posted here in another function